# Why do Americans put ‘my’ in front of everything?

Tags: american-english, speech

I watch a lot of Youtube, but I’ve also noticed this in movies.  North Americans tend to put the word *my* in front of stuff they tell you about; for example, *So I’ve got **my** grill fired up, I’ve got **my** oil heated*, etc.

In Sweden we would just say *I’ve got the grill fired up, and I’ve also heated the oil.*

Another example is from the movie *War of the Worlds*, from 2005 when Rachel says something like *You should get TiVo, we’ve got TiVo at home, I can watch all **MY** shows after I’ve done my homework.*

Note: I don’t count *my* before *homework*, because that seems legit.

Comment: In Italian many speakers would use the definite article instead of the possessive adjective. Italians say: "***The leg*** *is hurting me*" instead of "***My leg*** *is hurting me"*, *"Give me* **the hand**" instead of "Give me **a hand**". "The grill is ready" is perfectly acceptable in Italian too, but adding "my" shows who is the possessor, and "my grill" sounds better in English!

Comment: Because we Americans are selfish, possessive, and greedy? /sarc

Comment: Perhaps they feel the need to be proprietorial, a little concerned that some people see them as inferior (eg by capitalising Sweden but not americans).

Comment: Edwin Ashworth: Why would I capitalize "americans" it's not a name of a country like Sweden. I wouldn't capitalize swedes or norwegians either.

Comment: "Because we Americans are selfish, possessive, and greedy?"   Or maybe it's just common usage.  - as most of speech is.

Comment: @ravinki Because that’s how it’s done in English. Adjectives derived from country names are capitalised too, including when they’re nominalised; so _Swedish/Norwegian/American/Swedes/Norwegians/Americans_ are all capitalised in English. And this question has nothing to do with Americans—it’s a question of the English _language_. English tends to use possessive determiners in some cases where some other languages would use articles. And in your last example, Swedish too would use a possessive determiner before _shows_, not a definite article—that would change the meaning.

Comment: Note in my previous comment that the first letter in *Italian* and *English* are capitalized.

Comment: In cookery programmes, come to think of it, I do hear "my" being used a bit. I think it's just being friendly. *I've got my herbs chopped up nicely, and now I heat up the oil in my frying pan. Add my onions...* etc. That strikes me as being homely, down to earth, not selfish or egoistical as in: Those are *my* onions, not anyone else's! If you could find a youtube link with someone saying *my* several times, when "the" could be used instead, I'd upvote your question. I might even think about placing a bounty.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Here is a youtube link with a girl called Laura Vitale. 
She has a cooking show, and as you say, people with cooking shows tend to use "my" more often that others. Granted she does substitute "my" for "some" a couple of times, but she says e.g. "my glass bowl" "my apple sauce" etc. 
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmn0cfEm4S4)

Comment: If you could either list the number of times the cook says "my" when the definite article could be used   instead, or write the pertinent transcription that would save users the time finding out for themselves (read: no one will, if you don't).  The clip is quite lengthy too, 8 mins, you should note the time when "my XYZ" is used. I think the first time is at 2.05 *"First of all I want to mix together my dry ingredients"* 2.14 "... quarter teaspoon of nutmeg into my dry mix here" etc.

Comment: Some uses of "my" are colloquial/non-standard and could easily be replaced by "the" etc, but I don't know how you'd phrase "I can watch all MY shows after I’ve done my homework" so succinctly otherwise: "I can watch all the shows I've recorded after I’ve done my homework" or "I can watch all the shows I like to watch after I’ve done my homework"? Just saying "I can watch all the shows after I’ve done my homework" doesn't have the same meaning, nor would "I can watch shows after I’ve done my homework".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because a noun phrase in English calls for a determiner, and in English (as opposed to [other languages, such as Italian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_determiner#Comparison_with_determiners_and_adjectives)), *[possesive pronouns function as determiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_determiner#Possessive_determiners_in_English)*. To quote the linked Wikipedia article:

> The basic pronominal possessive determiners in modern English are *my, your, his, her, its, our, their and whose* (as in *Whose coat is this?* and *the man whose car was stolen*). As noted above, they indicate definiteness, like the definite article *the*.

As others have pointed out, the word *my* is often (for example, in *my grill*) arguably a semantically more suitable determiner than *the*, simply because it better conveys which grill is being meant.

Notably, it has nothing primarily to do with possession (cf. *my street*), but solely the combination of a grammatical obligation and a call for semantic clarity.

Comment: noun phrases in English do not always call for determiners. Case in point, neither of the noun phrases in the preceding sentence have one

Answer (score 3):

Using "my" in these cases emphasizes a personal connection to the subject, whether through choice, ownership, or another quality.  *My* shows indicates the shows this person chooses to watch (likely regularly), which says something about their identity.  *My* grill and *my* oil highlight the personal connection to the implements when cooking.  Tools or implements in particular seem to get this treatment frequently as they are agents of the speaker in a way.

Having some experience with Scandinavian mores, I'm not surprised that Swedish idioms would tend toward the less personal.